# In Scala, is it possible to zip two lists of differing sizes?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have

```
val letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
val numbers = (1, 2)
```

Is it possible to produce a list

```
(('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',1),('d',2),('e',1))
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your letters and numbers are tuples, not lists.  So let's fix that

```
scala> val letters = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
letters: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, d, e)

scala> val numbers = List(1,2)                    
numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Now, if we zip them we don't get the desired result

```
scala> letters zip numbers
res11: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2))
```

But that suggests that if numbers were repeated infinitely then the problem would be solved

```
scala> letters zip (Stream continually numbers).flatten
res12: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (d,2), (e,1))
```

Unfortunately, that's based on knowledge that numbers is shorter than letters.  So to fix it all up

```
scala> ((Stream continually letters).flatten zip (Stream continually numbers).flatten take (letters.size max numbers.size)).toList
res13: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (d,2), (e,1))
```

Comment: There's also `.zipAll` now, that takes two extra arguments, the default value for the first and second Collection that will be used to pad out if one is shorter than the other.

Answer (score 8):

The shorter of the lists needs to be repeated indefinitely. In this case it's obvious that `numbers` is shorter, but in case you need it to work in general, here is how you can do it:

```
def zipLongest[T](list1 : List[T], list2 : List[T]) : Seq[(T, T)] =
  if (list1.size < list2.size)
    Stream.continually(list1).flatten zip list2
  else
    list1 zip Stream.continually(list2).flatten

val letters = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
val numbers = List(1, 2)

println(zipLongest(letters, numbers))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do a simple one liner, using the `map` method

```scala
val letters = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
val numbers = List(1, 2)

val longZip1 = letters.zipWithIndex.map( x => (x._1, numbers(x._2 % numbers.length)) )

//or, using a for loop
//for (x <- letters.zipWithIndex) yield (x._1, numbers(x._2 % numbers.size))
```

And let's consider your lists are way longer:

```scala
val letters = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' /* 'f', ...*/)
val numbers = List(1, 2 /* 3, ... */)
val (longest, shortest) = (letters.toArray, numbers.toArray)

val longZip1 = longest
                 .zipWithIndex
                 .map(x => (x._1, shortest(x._2 % shortest.length)))
```

Comment: numbers(x._2 % numbers.length) will be very inneficient on a larger list, though. It would be better to convert numbers to an array to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to reuse any of the list data however you will need to know what the gaps are to be filled with ahead of time:

```
val result = (0 to (Math.max(list1.size, list2.size) - 1)) map { index =>  
(list1.lift(index).getOrElse(valWhen1Empty),list2.lift(index).getOrElse(valWhen2Empty))
}
```

I doubt this will work well with infinite lists or streams of course...