# Scala - finding first position in which two Seq differ

Tags: scala, diff, sequence, seq

Scala comes with the nice `corresponds` method:

```
val a = scala.io.Source.fromFile("fileA").getLines().toSeq()
val b = scala.io.Source.fromFile("fileB").getLines().toSeq()

val areEqual = a.corresponds(b){_.equals(_)}

if(areEqual) ...
```

And I quite like the brevity of that.

Is there a similar method already defined that will also report to me the first position in which the two sequences differ?

I.e. is there a more idiomatic way to write something like this:

```
val result = ((seqA zip seqB).zipWithIndex).find{case ((a,b),i) => !a.equals(b)} match{
    case Some(((a,b),i)) => s"seqA and seqB differ in pos $i: $a <> $b"
    case _ => "no difference"
}
```

Because as you can see, that's a bloody pain in the neck to read. And it gets even worse if I want to use triplets instead of tuples of tuples:

```
val result = (((seqA zip seqB).zipWithIndex) map {case (t,i) => (t._1,t._2,i)}).find{case (a,b,i) => !a.equals(b)} match{
    case Some((a,b,i)) => s"seqA and seqB differ in pos $i: $a <> $b"
    case _ => "no difference"
}
```

I am aware of the `diff` method. Unfortunately, that one disregards the order of the elements.

Comment: fyi: you should write `!a.equals(b)` as `a != b`

Comment: Aside: I don't think you need `case _ => false`  because `zip` will truncate the longer of the two inputs (if they differ in length) so your first case will always match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `indexWhere` (see [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@indexWhere%28p:A=%3EBoolean,from:Int%29:Int)) as follows:

```
(as zip bs).indexWhere{case (x,y) => x != y}
```

Example:

```
scala> val as = List(1,2,3,4)
scala> val bs = List(1,2,4,4)

scala> (as zip bs).indexWhere{case (x,y) => x != y}

res0: Int = 2
```

However, note that all solutions based on `zip` may report no differences if one Seq is longer than the other (`zip` truncates the longer Seq ) - this might or might not be what you need...

**Update**: For Seqs of equal length, a different approach is as follows:

```
as.indices.find(i => as(i) != bs(i))
```

This is nice as it returns an `Option[Int]`, so it returns `None` rather than a magical -1 if there is no difference between the Seqs.

It behaves the same as the other solution if `as` is shorter than `bs`, but fails if `as` is longer (you could take the minimum length, of course).

However, because it addresses both Seqs by index, it will only perform well for `IndexedSeq`s.

**Update 2**: We can deal with different Seq lengths by using `lift`, so that we get an Option when retrieving elements by index:

```
bs.indices.find(i => as.lift(i) != bs.lift(i))
```

so if `as = [1,2]` and `bs = [1,2,3]`, the first index by which they differ is 2 (because this element is missing in `as`). However, in this case we need to call `indices` on the longest Seq rather than the shortest - or explicitly check which is longest using `max`, e.g.

```
(0 until (as.length max bs.length)).find(i => as.lift(i) != bs.lift(i))
```

Comment: There's some solutions on zipping lists of mismatching sizes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621902/in-scala-is-it-possible-to-zip-two-lists-of-differing-sizes

Answer (score 3):

This is a little better:

```
(as zip bs).zipWithIndex.collectFirst { case ((a,b),i) if a!=b => i }
```

See:

```
def firstDiff[A,B](as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B]) = (as zip bs).zipWithIndex.collectFirst { case ((a,b),i) if a!=b => i }

firstDiff(Seq(1,2,3,4), Seq(1,2,9,4))
// res1: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

If you want `a` and `b` in the output:

```
(as zip bs).zipWithIndex.collectFirst { case ((a,b),i) if a!=b => (i,a,b) }
```

Also: if you want it like your `corresponds` example, you can do it as an extension method:

```
implicit class Enriched_counts_TraversableOnce[A](val as: TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def firstDiff[B](bs: TraversableOnce[B]): Option[Int] = {
    (as.toIterator zip bs.toIterator)
      .zipWithIndex
      .collectFirst { case ((a,b),i) if a!=b => i }
  }
}

Seq(1,2,3,4).firstDiff(Seq(1,2,9,4))
// res2: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Or even:

```
implicit class Enriched_counts_TraversableOnce[A](val as: TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def firstDiff2[B](bs: TraversableOnce[B])(p: (A,B) => Boolean): Option[Int] = {
    (as.toIterator zip bs.toIterator)
      .zipWithIndex
      .collectFirst { case ((a,b),i) if !p(a,b) => i }
  }
}

Seq(1,2,3,4).firstDiff2(Seq(1,2,9,4)){ _ == _ }
// res3: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```