# How to Zip Two Lists, of Which One Only Has One Element or More (Combine Elements One by One From Two List)

Tags: scala

Here is an example of two lists:

```
scala> val hosts = List("host1", "host2")
hosts: List[String] = List(host1, host2)

scala> val ports = List("port1")
ports: List[String] = List(port1)
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
scala> hosts zip ports
List[(String, String)] = List((host1,port1), (host2,port1))
```

Result below is what I get, which may be expected but I am still in the process of learning. would appreciate any help.

```
scala> hosts zip ports
res20: List[(String, String)] = List((host1,port1))
```

Note: at least one element on each list any time but it varies. regardless I would like to achieve one by one pairing.

Comment: What should happen if list 1 has three elements and the list 2 has two elements?

Comment: Have you tried [zipAll](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#zipAll[A1%3E:A,B](that:Iterable[B],thisElem:A1,thatElem:B):CC[(A1,B)]) ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez no change. got same result as in the question.

Comment: @jrook zipAll doesn't give expected result I mentioned. but I found the answer here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621902/in-scala-is-it-possible-to-zip-two-lists-of-differing-sizes

Comment: You could mark the question as duplicate or post an answer if it is rather different than the question you linked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two lists, in which case you can use `for`:

```
for {
  h <- hosts
  p <- ports
} yield (h, p)
```

If you just want to `zip` two lists of different lengths then you can use `zipAll`

```
hosts.zipAll(ports, defaultHost, defaultPort)
```

This will pad the shorter list with the appropriate default value and then `zip` them as usual.

Comment: your first one also works. this is another solution I got from the link in my comment

     Scala> hosts zip (Stream continually ports).flatten
 I had to swap the list based on length for it to properly but yours is cleaner Thanks.

Comment: `zip` and *Cartesian Product* are completely different. The OP is asking for `zip`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag agreed zip and Cartesian are different. but I was actually trying to achieve Cartesian product using zip but it seemed a lost case.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Please re-open this question as the answer you claim is a duplicate is about `zip` which the OP has just said is *not* what they were asking about.

Comment: @Tim: [The OP has stated explicitly in a comment that the duplicate question answers their Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013633/how-to-zip-two-lists-of-which-one-only-has-one-element-or-more-combine-element/60015123?noredirect=1#comment106138958_60013633). Quote: "I found the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621902/in-scala-is-it-possible-to-zip-two-lists-of-differing-sizes".

Comment: I would have voted Tim's as solution but it came later and I had marked others already. regardless I think Tim's answer nicer. Tried to upvote but can't it says locked.